# Colab to Pycharm Library import problem in Pycharm

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, google-colaboratory

I want to import the code I'm working in **colab** into **pycharm**. However, when importing libraries, I get an error on the pycharm side.

[Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gV9U.png)

The code works in colab, but it throws an error in pycharm because of libraries. How can I import these libraries in pycharm?

Error is here:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj3is.png)

Comment: Please edit your post, to include the actual inclusions and PyCharm output, as _Code Samples_ and not as links to screen captions.

Comment: I don't have a code sample, because the libraries are not being imported, which is my problem. How can I import this?

Comment: You have to edit the question to include the error stacktrace as text, as well as the code.